# How to play in line headphones and bluetooth simultaneously iOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Xcode Swift! How to play sound in line headphones and bluetooth simultaneously?

Comment: I think that is not possible yet, but you can check this post http://devmonologue.com/ios/tutorials/avaudiosession-bluetooth-support/

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think there's a way to do it. Since the signal of the headphone-jack is analog, it kind of deactivates the audio signal for the speakers and or bluetooth.

Not sure though.